# Set multiple div side by side with CanvasJS charts using CSS

Tags: html, css, canvasjs

Im currerntly using Canvas Js to show different charts. In one of the requirement i would like to show multiple charts side by side. These are mostly doughnut charts. However im unable to achieve it.

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lqw6a2dq/

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/SujitJ/zm0gbp80/8/

CSS:

```
.container{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;    
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Currently in the fiddle i have just included 2 div for charts but the no. of div would be dynamic hence would need a dynamic solution for the placement of div

Comment: In your fiddle you use `<div id="container">`, and in CSS code you use selector for `class="container"`.

Comment: ah! you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.appendchild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) in a while loop to render the div that you want in a dynamic way.

You first create a variable, where you will tell in which element ( we take the id of the element ) you want to append the divs.

```
var div = document.getElementById('container');
```

Then we do a simple `while` loop.

```
{
 if(!document.getElementById('chartContainer'+i))
  {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");//we say what element we should create, a div in our case
    ele.setAttribute("id","chartContainer"+i);//add the id to our element
    div.appendChild(ele);     
  }
  i++;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqw6a2dq/1/

Use inspect element to see the two divs. If you want to add more divs, just change the number in `while(i<=2)`to whatever you need.

Comment: Updated my fiddle. To be honest, I thought you wanted to add the divs in a more dynamic way, so you don't have to manually add divs all the time. Glad you solved it, though.

Comment: currently in the Working fiddle i have added the 3 divs as static but in the actual code i have used JSTL forEach loop to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class = "container" to set your classes in row with equal dimensions.

```html
<div class= "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Chart 1</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">Chart 2</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">Chart 3</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

If number of charts are different or dynamic, you can choose class col-md-4 at run time using javascript DOM.